# MessageBox doesn't show Folder path when two keywords are searched, but it shows the folder path when one keyword is searched

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

```
            try
            {

                string[] SetupFolderKeywords = {"Setup", "Installed"}; 
                DirectoryInfo SearchedDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Game.SelectedPath);
                FileSystemInfo[] filesAndDirs = SearchedDirectory.GetFileSystemInfos($"*{SetupFolderKeywords[0]}*|*{SetupFolderKeywords[1]}*"); // <-- This doesn't work
                // FileSystemInfo[] filesAndDirs = SearchedDirectory.GetFileSystemInfos("*" + SetupFolderKeywords[0] + "*"); <-- This Works
                foreach (FileSystemInfo foundFile in filesAndDirs)
                {
                  string FullName = foundFile.FullName;
                  MessageBox.Show(FullName);
                }

            }
            catch (IOException ExpMoveFolder)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ExpMoveFolder));
            }
```

I'm trying to look for a folder that has either the keyword "Setup" or "Installed" inside the Game.SelectedPath directory. (I used a FolderBrowserDialog to select this folder) and make a MessageBox appear with its path.

When I try to search for a folder that matches one keyword, the MessageBox appears with the path of the folder. It works great, but when I try to search for keyword "Setup" or "Installed" MessageBox doesn't show at all.

No error messages or warnings appear in visual studio and no program exception occurs when I try to look for either one of the keywords instead of just one keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for multiple patterns with a single call. Your attempt at a Boolean expression is just interpreted as a single pattern and, of course, there are no entries that match that pattern. If you want to match multiple patterns then you have to make multiple calls. One option might be like this:

```cs
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(Game.SelectedPath);
var entries = folder.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(patterns[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < patterns.Length; i++)
{
    entries = entries.Concat(folder.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(patterns[i]));
}

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    // Use entry here.
}
```

EDIT:

I just created this folder:

[image]

I then executed this code:

```cs
var patterns = new[] { "123", "789" };
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Test"));
var entries = folder.EnumerateFileSystemInfos($"*{patterns[0]}*");

for (var i = 1; i < patterns.Length; i++)
{
    entries = entries.Concat(folder.EnumerateFileSystemInfos($"*{patterns[i]}*"));
}

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
}
```

That's basically exactly what I posted above except I added wildcards to the `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` calls where the original code would have required them to be in `strings` already. This is the output I got:

```
File123.txt
Folder123
File789.txt
Folder789
```

I then changed the filters to this:

```cs
var patterns = new[] { "456" };
```

and ran the code again and got this output:

```
File456.txt
Folder456
```

Clearly, the code works exactly as it is supposed to and, if what you did didn't work then you did it wrong. If you can't work out what you did wrong, I suggest that you update your question and add the new relevant information.

Comment: I replaced patterns with SetupFolderKeywords and folder with Game.SelectedPath
I put MessageBox.Show(Test) under foreach (var entry in entries) and the messageBox only shows when folders with SetupFolderKeywords[0] is selected. I would've shared my code with you but sadly it's way past the characters limit.
Is there anything I should keep in mind to avoid issues like this?